# updating records by putting sum(column) value

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have table1 like this:

```
+-----+-----+------+
| cat | val | type |
+-----+-----+------+
| A   | 100 | c1   |
| H   | 25  | c2   |
| H   | 50  | c3   |
| H   | 30  | c2   |
| A   | 15  | c3   |
| H   | 10  | c1   |
| H   | 15  | c1   |
| B   | 10  | c4   |
| H   | 20  | c4   |
| H   | 15  | c3   |
+-----+-----+------+
```

I need to add the sum(val) group by type to only one H belonging to each type

So I have after grouping by type we have say table2 :

```
+-----+-----+
| cat | val |
+-----+-----+
| c1  | 125 |
| c2  | 55  |
| c3  | 80  |
| c4  | 30  |
+-----+-----+
```

I need 125 added to any one H values with type c1, 55 added to any one H values with c2, and so on..If there is no H with c1,then it should create that record.

So finally we get:

```
    +-----+-----+------+
    | cat | val | type |
    +-----+-----+------+
    | A   | 100 | c1   |
    | H   | 25  | c2   |
    | H   | 130 | c3   |
    | H   | 85  | c2   |
    | A   | 15  | c3   |
    | H   | 135 | c1   |
    | H   | 15  | c1   |
    | B   | 10  | c4   |
    | H   | 50  | c4   |
    | H   | 15  | c3   |
    +-----+-----+------+
```

How do I do it without doing table1 union table2 (with 'H' as cat) group by type? Also I don't have update privileges and cannot use stored procedures. I also have to keep in mind that table1 is a result of a query involving multiple inner joins that I don't want to use over and over again for select statements.

Comment: Why doesn't the row `| H   | 25  | c2   |` change at all?  Same for `| H   | 15 | c1   |` and `| H   | 15  | c3   |`?

Comment: @MatBailie because the need is to update any one (H,Cs) combination and not more than that

Answer (score 0):

See whether this makes sense. I've added the ID column just to display the final result in the same order as the input (for easier reading).

```
SQL> -- T1 is what you currently have; it can/could be your current query
SQL> with t1 (id, cat, val, type) as
  2    (select 1, 'A', 100, 'C1' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'H', 25 , 'C2' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'H', 50 , 'C3' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'H', 30 , 'C2' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'A', 15 , 'C3' from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'H', 10 , 'C1' from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'H', 15 , 'C1' from dual union all
  9     select 8, 'B', 10 , 'C4' from dual union all
 10     select 9, 'H', 20 , 'C4' from dual union all
 11     select 10,'H', 15 , 'C3' from dual
 12    ),
 13  -- sum VAL per type
 14  t1_sum as
 15    (select type, sum(val) sum_val
 16     from t1
 17     group by type
 18    ),
 19  -- find row number; let any H be number 1
 20  t1_rn as
 21    (select id, cat, val, type,
 22       row_number() over (partition by type
 23                          order by case when cat = 'H' then 1 end) rn
 24     from t1
 25    )
 26  -- the final result; add SUM_VAL to the first H row per type
 27  select r.cat, r.val + case when r.rn = 1 then s.sum_val else 0 end val,
 28    r.type
 29  From t1_rn r join t1_sum s on s.type = r.type
 30  order by r.id;

CAT        VAL TYPE
--- ---------- ----
A          100 C1
H           80 C2
H          130 C3
H           30 C2
A           15 C3
H          135 C1
H           15 C1
B           10 C4
H           50 C4
H           15 C3

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: trying to clarify how to use your large query]**

Suppose that this is that very large and complex query of yours:

```
select a.cat, 
       case when a.cat = 'A' then b.val 
            when a.cat = 'Z' then c.val
            else 'H'
       end val,
       c.type
from a join b on a.id = b.id and a.x = b.y
       join c on c.id = b.idx
where a.date_column < sysdate
  and c.type = 'X';
```

As I've said, create a view based on it as

```
create or replace view v_view as
select a.cat, 
       case when a.cat = 'A' then b.val 
            when a.cat = 'Z' then c.val
            else 'H'
       end val,
       c.type
from a join b on a.id = b.id and a.x = b.y
       join c on c.id = b.idx
where a.date_column < sysdate
  and c.type = 'X';
```

and use it as a source for "my" query (from line 14 onwards):

```
with t1_sum as
  (select type, sum(val) sum_val
   from v_view                      --> here's the view
   group by type
  ), etc.
```

---

Or, use the "huge" query itself as the initial CTE:

```
with t1 as
-- this is your "huge" query
(select a.cat,  
       case when a.cat = 'A' then b.val 
            when a.cat = 'Z' then c.val
            else 'H'
       end val,
       c.type
from a join b on a.id = b.id and a.x = b.y
       join c on c.id = b.idx
where a.date_column < sysdate
  and c.type = 'X'
),
-- sum VAL per type
t1_sum as
  (select type, sum(val) sum_val
   from t1
   group by type
  ), etc.
```

Comment: But how to do it if the no of records in table1 are very high ? In the actual scenario , I would have around 5 million records in the table. I surely cannot select using ID invidually

Comment: And also I want to use t1 just once since it has multiple inner joins and lots of case statements which makes the query look very cumbersome when used more than once.

Comment: Your "large query with multiple inner joins and lots of case statements" would be my T1 CTE. If you hate seeing it, create a view based on that query.  Who said anything about selecting individual IDs? If you're referring to "my ID" column, then re-read again what I've said about it. Finally, I don't have any objections if you write your own code (or wait a little bit longer or indefinitely for someone else to post another option). Shortly: take it or leave it.

Comment: Will certainly "take it" with just a few clarifications-1.how do I write the statements "select 1, 'A', 100, 'C1' from dual union all ..." for all the rows I have in my table and 2. If I use a complex view will I be able to do further group by on it ? Anyways thanks for making the efforts to answer

Comment: I've edited my message and added some more code which, hopefully, shows what I meant. Have a look, please. Does it make some more sense now?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed

Comment: OK; I'm glad if it helped.

Comment: Just one clarification needed if any particular (H,Cs) is not present it puts the sum(val) for that Cs to the other values in cat where rn =1 . For example if H,20,C4 is not present then B,10,C4 is incremented to B,20,C4 instead of creating a record with H,10,C4.

Comment: Huh, right ... you mentioned that requirement in the question. It makes things complicated and I don't know whether you can (or can not) do something "procedural" in a single query. Unfortunately, it seems that you can't do *a lot of things* which might help doing that. Therefore, try to expand code I suggested with another query which checks absence of the H cat and UNION (ALL) a new row with the existing result set.